# X serverにconnectionしないようにしたい

Tags: docker

アプリケーションから画像ファイルを保存するためには、Viewerを起動しなければなりません。
しかし、dockerの中からViewerを起動しても、出力先がないので、次のようにエラーになります。

vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0xd7e860): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=/usr/local/bin/********: line 86:    30 Aborted                 (core dumped)

エラーを起こさないためにはどうしたらよろしいでしょうか。
環境は、ローカル、Docker ともにubuntuです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ｢アプリケーション｣とは何ですか?自作のものの場合,スニペットを書いたほうが良いと思います.｢アプリケーションから画像ファイルを保存するためには、Viewerを起動しなければなりません。｣と書かれていますが,画像でもただのファイルであることは変わりないので,Xが必要であるとは思えません,また｢Viewer｣とは一体何でしょうか?詳細がわからないので答えにくいですが,方針としてはXを使わずにファイルを保存すれば良いと思います.

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。アプリケーションが扱っているものは「点群データ」なので、「点群データ」を画像にするにはViewerを使わなくてはなりません。そして、Viewerを起動すると画面を出力しようとします。だから、画面を出力しない方法、出力してもエラーにならない方法があればうれしく思います。

Comment: これは Docker を動かしているローカルの OS と、Docker 内で動いている OS によって対処法が変わりえます。環境情報を追記してください。

Comment: 具体的なアプリ名を挙げてもらった方がアドバイスも具体的なものになると思います。

Comment: 環境は、ローカル、Docker ともにubuntuです。具体的なアプリ名を掲げても、誰もわからないと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 分からないと判断するのは質問者さんではなく、回答しようとする人です。

Comment: 問題を解決するには「再現性」も重要な情報なので、個人情報などは伏せるべきですが、その他は些細なことでもなるべく記述しておくべきです。逆に言うと、ただエラーメッセージだけ見せられても他人が同じ環境を再現できなければアドバイスのしようがありません。

Answer (score 1):

アプリケーションがGUIであるなら、環境変数DISPLAYにはXサーバが起動しているマシンのIPアドレス(またはホスト名)を正しく設定する必要があります。
エラーメッセージに出ている`DISPLAY=/usr/local/bin/***`はなんらかのファイルのパスなので、明らかに間違っています。

> vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0xd7e860): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=/usr/local/bin/********: line 86: 30 Aborted (core dumped)

具体的なアプリ名が出ていないので的外れになるかもしれませんが、エラーメッセージの一部でweb検索してみると以下の様なページが見つかりましたので参考までに。

[[vtkusers] Rendering to images without X (Linux)?](https://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2010-August/062257.html)
[VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/OffScreenRendering - KitwarePublic](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/OffScreenRendering)

Answer (score 1):

Viewerについては情報がないので、X Server に Connection しないようにする方法はわかりませんが、Docker ホストの X.orgサーバー上に表示されば良いんじゃないでしょうか。

コンテナ実行時に 環境変数DISPLAYを指定して、ホストのX11プロトコルのソケットを -v オプションで指定してみてください。

例)

```
# docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix viewer
```

上手く行けば XクライアントであるViewerが起動すると、Dockerホスト上のX.orgサーバーに接続され、GUIが Dockerホストの 画面に表示されると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試したところ、次のエラー表示になりました。参考になりますか。ERROR: In /build/vtk6-YpT4yb/vtk6-6.2.0+dfsg1/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 1466vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x118bf90): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=localhost:0. Aborting.

Comment: Dockerホスト上で、`xhost +` を実行してから `docker run ...` を行うとどうなりますか？